# Do a 8-bit write to a 32-bit register

Tags: c, memory-management, arm, cpu-registers

I'm trying to read the `clock source` value of a given `generic clock generator` on the Samd21 MCU.

The datasheet says, that if I wish to read the `GENCTRL` register (containing the clock source value), I need to "do a 8-bit write" and read the register afterwards. How can I do that, given that the register is 32-bit?

I'm afraid, that by doing the following, I am actually changing the `generic clock generator X`'s configuration:

```
GCLK->GENCTRL.reg = GCLK->GENCTRL.reg & 0xFFFFFFF0 | 0x0000000X
```

Keep in mind, that the lower 8-bits of `GENCTRL` are reserved for the generic clock generator's ID.

Bellow is part of the [datasheet](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Dev/Arduino/Boards/Atmel-42181-SAM-D21_Datasheet.pdf) containing the instructions for reading the `GENCTRL` register.

[image: Datasheet]

Comment: do an strb then an ldr

Comment: Atomic 8-, 16- and 32-bit accesses are supported. In addition, the 8-bit quarters and 16-bit halves of a 32-bit register, and
the 8-bit halves of a 16-bit register can be accessed directly.

Comment: from the PAC section, assuming that when they say there is  PAC per AHB/APB bridge that means all peripherals are 8, or 16, or 32 bit addressable.  The way the register documentation is written also implies this.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. So how can I write just the lower 8 bits? I'm guessing writing GCLK->GENCTRL.reg = 0x0 is incorrect.

Comment: Well if your library/header has a way to do byte based accesses using the volatile pointer trick otherwise it would be a serious problem if using a 32 bit pointer in C results in an 8 bit access (although I have seen it happen and as a result strongly advise against using the volatile pointer tricks or worse never ever misuse a union or use a struct across compile domains which is most likely what your headers have provided).

Comment: use real assembly, if gnu assembler then .thumb_func;  .globl PUT8; PUT8: strb r1,[r0].   Then call it from C PUT8(address,data);  The address is shown in the chip documentation that you linked.  Or you can make a very small funciton using the pointer thing and disassemble to find the address.

Comment: If you have these headers/pointers setup then there are no doubt libraries too, just grep through them for GENCTRL and find out how they did it.

Comment: @old_timer thanks for the tips. In the end I did an extensive search of the libraries and found the place, where GENCTRL was set, which gave me the answer.

Comment: That would have been my first way to figure this out, and perhaps despite the statement by the documentation a wider write might also work,  but you know more than we do at this point as you have found supposedly working code.

Answer (score 1):

The ARM registers are 32 bit. The peripheral registers (in general) will be arranged at 4 byte offsets, but will not always implement all 32 bits that this implies.

This is most obvious when the upper bits of a peripheral register are 'read as zero, write ignored'. You might occasionally see a newer or more featured version of the peripheral where some of these unused bits become used in the future.

Depending on exactly how a specific peripheral is connected to the core it is generally possible to perform byte, half-word or word accesses to any region of memory. Provided this is supported, only the relevant bytes will be updated. Where there is a restriction (for example a 32 bit APB bus where only byte access is supported), this should be clearly identified in the documentation. With a AA64 processor, it is even possible to write two registers at once!

Do note that the peripheral 'knows' the access size (at least the information is present on the internal bus), so it is possible to specify different behaviour for a byte access as a word (even if this is the sort of confusing behaviour that is best avoided). To generalise, any memory mapped peripheral is more of an observer of the bus than a true implementation of memory - the designer is free to play tricks with the full address/data/control bus bit combinations, and implement bitmasks, read/modify/write, access locks, magic values, etc.